# Move text cursor to lines that are not visible in screen using C++

Tags: c++, terminal, console

I'm currently writing a C++ console application that runs an optimization routine. It runs several processes in parallel and as it takes some hours to finish, I created a kind of monitor to follow the processes evolution. I implemented this by means of printing a table in screen and every time that a process step is changed the text cursor is moved to the row referent to that process and the older text is overwritten  by the newer.
To do the movement through the table rows I used "\n" for moving the text cursor a row down and the ESC character "\033[F" for moving the cursor a row up.

The problem is that sometimes the table has a number of rows greater than the number of lines that fit in screen, so some rows stay hidden and one needs scrolling the screen to see them. When application moves the text cursor up or down, it cannot go until the lines that are hidden, stopping at the first or last visible lines, respectively. I would like to know if there is some way of access the lines that are beyond the visible screen area.

Comment: Look into the `ncurses` library.

Comment: Consider a proper GUI :)

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, take a look at this under `<Windows.h>` ,

```
HANDLE hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
SetConsoleCursorPosition(hStdout, { 20, 4 });
```

Where, "4" refers to row (or line for better understanding) and "20" refers to column (or cursor position on line).